# Regular expression matching href=

Tags: php, regex

I've been looking for a few days now, trying to match href links but I need to reduce the results so that the start of the href is:

```
<a href="/hp/
```

Does anyone know a regular expression that could do this?

Comment: Can you clarify the source data and the desired end result?

Comment: Please provide a lot more detail! An example of what you are trying to match would be useful.

Comment: Do you mean that <a href="/hp/blabla.html"> has to be matched and you want href value, but <a href="http://www.example.com"> doesn't have to be matched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('/<a href=["\']?(\/load\/[^"\'\s>]+)["\'\s>]?/i', $string);
```

This matches:

```
<a href="/load/anytext">
```

and returns its href value, but not

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">
```

Pay attention: if you want the regex to match also href="/load/" without other text then you have to substitute the + before the ? with a *, else this regex matches only href="/load/anytext..."

Comment: @  CaNNaDaRk  yes thats what i want im struggling im not that good with regex

Comment: Thanks, now this should work even without quotes or with single quotes. Edited again ;)

Comment: preg_match('/<a href=["\']?(\/load\/.+?)["\']?/i', $string);
worked perfectly thank you

Comment: This will fail for `href="/load/Moore's Law"`. `preg_match('/<a href=(["\']?)(\/load\/[^\g{1}]+?)\g{1}[\s>]/i', $string)` seems to work, though. :)

Comment: @rczajka That will fail for `<a href=/load/foo class=bubbles />` :-)

Comment: No it won't. `preg_match('/<a href=(["\']?)(\/load\/[^\g{1}]+?)\g{1}[\s>]/i', '<a href=/load/foo class=bubbles />', $m); echo $m[2];` gives `/load/foo`.